# Is it possible to set the width of tooltips in Visual Studio Code Editor windows?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, f#, xml-comments

For just about all languages I program in, I am often annoyed by the width of the tooltips caused by XML auto-documentation comments. In some cases I started prepending each line with a `<para />`, but then I have to filter them out again when generating documentation.

An easier solution would be to set the width of these tooltips. Is anybody aware of a setting, or registry trick that can be used here?

Example of what I see on my wide screen, which I think is totally unintelligible:

[image: Tooltip width craziness...]

Actually, using `<para />` works for F#, but in C# it adds a white line between each paragraph (which makes sense, but is not what I'm after). As is well known, line breaks with `<br />` get ignored in XML comments.

Not quite the idea:

[image]

But think of this image without the blank lines, then you get the idea of what I am hoping for (against all odds ;).